# build jar from loopj android-async-http source

Tags: java, android, maven, jar, android-async-http

I'm trying to build a jar from the https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http source code but have been unsuccessful.

I also tried including the source as a library in my android project in android studio but was unable to.

I want to build from source because the jar's available in maven and in the github repo are too old and I want to use and test some of the new features available in the source.

How can I either build the jar and include the jar in my android studio project or simply properly include the source in my android studio project?

Comment: It seems that for this particular android library I need to instruct gradle to push to a directory in the filesystem instead of pushing to maven. Not sure how to do that though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to build the jar myself in ubuntu:

```
cd  android-async-http/library
gradle build
```

That generated a `build` directory that contained a jar of the library.

Comment: That's great. So with me it generated a build directory and the jar was put in the build/libs directory.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need a Jar or you want to build the jar yourself. If you are just looking for the jar, they are already compiled and ready to download on this link [here](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/tree/master/releases).

Looks like github download is not working. Use [this](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) link to download the latest android-async-http jar

Comment: I want to build the jar myself because the pre-built ones don't have some fixes that are in the source code.